# C# convert "label.text" string to integer

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox

I am attempting to create a pic-box in a form that when clicked within a particular X/Y range(rectangle), a second form opens. My problem is getting the string values of lblX and lblY to act correctly within my 'If' statement below:

```
  private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
        Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

        if ((lblX >= 155 && lblX <= 179) && (lblY >= 145 && lblY <= 160))
        {
            Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
            Form2.Show();
        }
    }
```

Hopefully it's clear what I'm trying to do. The error is stating "the operator >= cannot be used with label and int". Can anyone see what I'm missing and recommend a solution?

Thanks, A.

Answer (score 9):

`Convert.ToInt32` *returns* the integer value. You need to assign it:

```
var x = Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
var y = Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

if ((x >= 155 && x <= 179) && (y >= 145 && y <= 160))
{
    Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
    Form2.Show();
}
```

Also consider using `int.TryParse` and handling failed conversions in the case of bad input:

```
int x;
int y;
if (!int.TryParse(lblX.Text, out x) || !int.TryParse(lblY.Text, out y))
{
    // Oh no, a problem! Do something, quick!
}
else
{
    if ((x >= 155 && x <= 179) && (y >= 145 && y <= 160))
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, That has corrected my initial problem. The program runs ok, but when clicked I now receive the following error: "formatException ... input string was not in the correct format" and points to the conversion statements?

Comment: Then the values of the label strings are not integers.

Answer (score 3):

The `Convert.ToInt32` returns an `int` so you'll need to assign that to a variable first, then check the variable

```
private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

    if ((x >= 155 && x <= 179) && (y >= 145 && y <= 160))
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You are converting the label's text to integers but you are not saving them anywhere, later you are comparing Labels against those values, it should be like:

```
private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int X = Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
    int Y = Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

    if ((X >= 155 && X <= 179) && (Y >= 145 && Y <= 160))
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }
}
```

Store the result of conversion in variables `X` and `Y` and later compare those in your condition.

You may also look at [int.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) methods for safer parsing *(no exception is raised in case of failed parsing)*. Also consider using [Microsoft coding conventions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff926074.aspx) for variable naming.

Answer (score 3):

`Convert.ToInt32`  returns an `int` you should assign it to a variable to compare the converted label value to your coordinates

```
 private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
             int lx= Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
             int ly =Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

            if ((lx >= 155 && lx <= 179) && (ly >= 145 && ly <= 160))
            {
                Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
                Form2.Show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to store the results of the conversion into variables.

```
private void picboxMain_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    int x = Convert.ToInt32(lblX.Text);
    int y = Convert.ToInt32(lblY.Text);

    if ((x >= 155 && x <= 179) && (y >= 145 && y <= 160))
    {
        Form2 Form2 = new Form2();
        Form2.Show();
    }
}
```